# What is the synonym of "pixel pusher" for programmers?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

"Pixel pusher" is the ironic expression denominating graphical designers (see [this article](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=pixel%20pusher&defid=576473)).

What would be the similar expression for programmers?

---

I would like to emphasize the user interface aspect. I am thinking about the equivalent to the Russian expression "клепатель формочек", which can be loosely translated as "the person who makes GUI forms".

Comment: Perhaps _bit cruncher_?

Comment: Code monkey, code-slinger, bit-pusher...

Comment: "Bit twiddler" is what I used to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course that's a question of slang and preference, but I'm partial to *code monkey*.

Mostly because of [the Jonathan Coulton song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kWrjYdD0Tg).

Comment: It seems that "code monkey" is much more ironic, isn't it? Even sarcastic, I would say.

Comment: Yes? That's how I read “pixel pusher.”